# Lattice polytope toric varieties under rescaling

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Is there any interesting relation/map between the toric variety $X_P$ associated to a lattice polytope $P$ and the toric variety associated to the polytope rescaled by some integer factor?

Comment: A polytope is not only a toric variety,  it also comes with a line bundle. Multiplying the polytope boils down to take tensor power of L.

Comment: (So if P is very ample, nothing changes. Otherwise I'm not really sure what one can say)

Comment: does it mean that there is some map - maybe described in homogeneous variables - sending one variety into the other?

Comment: do you have any reference (maybe with examples) where this is explained?

Comment: Toric varieties by Cox, Schenck and Little should contain it (and a lot more!)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, yes there is a natural map from the toric variety associated to P to that associated to dP, namely the d-uple Veronese embedding.